# Is k nearest neighbours regression inherently slow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to use k nearest neighbours implementation from scikit learn on a fairly large dataset. The problem is that predictions take a very long time, almost as long as training which doesn't make sense. Is it an issue with the algorithm, or the fact that scikit learn isn't made for large datasets (no GPU support).

For further information, I am trying to predict lidar intensity based on x, y, z and object label. Each lidar scan has ~100,000 points, so I'm trying to predict the intensity for each point.

Comment: Are you passing all points together or one at a time? Any k-nearest neighbor will need to find out the distance of a point from all points present in training. Sending multiple at once will help (matrix calculations used inside)

Comment: @VivekKumar Not sure if it answers the question but I am using `knn_regressor.predict(X)` method from scikit learn, where `X` is a `(120738, 20)` array with x, y, z, depth and one-hot encoded object labels. I trained the model on a very large dataset, so I guess this is why prediction takes so long (as you said, it's calculating the distance to all points from the training set), so in theory, training on less points should help?

Comment: Maybe. But that may hit the performance. You can try different parameters for sklearn knn like changing `leaf_size` or distance metric. First try with `n_jobs=-1` if not already to start multiprocessing

Comment: Why is it strange? In KNN regression there is no real 'training'. As it is nonparametric method, it uses data itself to make predictions. Parametric models make predictions fast, since they rely on a model. KNN does not have model, so prediction is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Things to try to make scikit-learn's [`KNeighborsClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)  run faster:

- different `algorithm` parameter: `kd_tree`, `ball_tree` for low dimensional data, `brute` for high dimensional data
- `n_jobs` parameter. Using a larger `n_jobs` doesn't necessarily make things faster, sometimes the opposite.
- make sure you are using the latest version: there have been performance improvements in [v0.22](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.22.html#sklearn-neighbors) and some not yet merged optimizations ([scikit-learn#14543](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/14543))
- use an external approximate nearest neighbours library (e.g. [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)) together with pre-computed sparse distances using [`metric="precomputed"`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10482)